# How to find and fix address errors?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset (65,000 observations) that has an address column with multiple errors.
Some of the errors I have observed are: 10th avenue, TENTH avenue, or AVE and avenue, etc. Some even just have an extra space in between words. Obviously there are more errors but as the dataset is so large I can't find all of them myself.

So I want to know if there is code that I could write that would automatically identify my errors for me?
And then what code I could write to fix them after?

Comment: Welcome to SO and also to the world of working with IRL data. You do it by rolling up your sleeves and making a plan to address the most common to least common diversions from the norm in the way the data was recorded. You should first define what the standard is for the field values and write some code to identify the observations that deviate from it and then go from there. While Randall's suggestion is on the right track, I'm not sure potentially destroying properly recorded values by wanton case manipulation of the column of original values is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, fair point. It might be better to create a new column like 'clean_address' and send all changes there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with gsub()

From the example you have given

```
example <- example %>%
  #put all items in consistent case
  mutate(address = str_to_title(address),
         #fix Tenth to 10th
         address = gsub('Tenth','10th',address),
         #fix Ave to Avenue
         address = gsub('Ave','Avenue',address))
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly. Do you know of a way to find errors using code? Or will I need to manually edit whatever errors I can find?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by 'errors'. ;) If you have something like '10th' vs 'Tenth' that's not really an error from the perspective of a computer, as they are just string values. You need to be the one to define what you want to change, and what you want to change it to. There are packages like `hunspell` that you can use for checking spelling, but that wouldn't apply to '10th' vs 'Tenth'.

Comment: Okay all good, just thought I would ask. Thanks for your help the code has worked perfectly for what I need to do.

Comment: Also, is there something I could add to the code to make everything capitals?

Comment: yeah, there are a bunch of ways to do that. I usually use the str_to_upper function from the `stringr` package: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/case.html